# Method doesn't exist (MainActivity.java)

Tags: java, android

I am very new to Android. Please give me a solution. I am in confusion. I have below line of code in

activity_main.xml file:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/exit_img"
        android:src = "@drawable/exit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:onClick="exitsys()"
        android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical" />
```

and in MainActivity.java file below lines of code:

```
public void exitsys(View v){

                    System.exit(0);

    }
```

But Android Studio is giving error that **"Method exitsys() is missing in 'MainActivity' or has incorrect signature"**

I don't know what mistake I did. Also as information, I am new to Java as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove "()" from method name

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/exit_img"
    android:src = "@drawable/exit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:onClick="exitsys"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical" />
```

Also to exit an activity use `finish()`; using `System.exit(0)` is a bad idea.

So use this

```
public void exitsys(View v){
                finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exit from the Activity, you should use the method

```
finish();
```

It will close the Activity. If your app don't have any other activity bellow, it will close the application.
You seem to be very new to the Android universe. Take a look at the trainning guide in the developer website.

http://developer.android.com/training/index.html

It is very instructive.

Comment: Of course we shouldn't use `System.exit(0)` but reason of non-working code is different.